# E.KeyCode and Regex in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, winforms, keycode

How i can make this condition en VB.NET

```
If e.KeyCode = [a-zA-Z0-9] Then
  'Blah
End if
```

I have understood that the Keycode are numbers but as I can do this validation with regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Dim reg_exp As New Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]")
        If reg_exp.IsMatch(e.KeyCode.ToString) Then
            'Blah
        End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use .Net's [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f.aspx), which also allows Unicode characters:

Example: http://ideone.com/7ykE0